# Are there any sentient plant species in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, aliens

There are a variety of different species in *Star Trek*, from all walks of life. Humanoids, insectoids, silicon-based life-forms, the works. However, I can't seem to think of any sentient plant species from across all the *Star Trek* shows/films. Are there any that exist, throughout all of the canon? Examples from the animated series will also be included, in all its weirdness.

Comment: I do recall one of the funnier episodes of _Lost in Space_, but that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Sure. Lieutenant Broccoli.

Comment: Weren't the tribbles sentient in a sort of hive mind, collectivist sense? Or were they animal not plant?

Comment: Why are there three identical answers?

Comment: Said like a true @HamSandwich.

Comment: I think you might need to clarify the distinction between _plant_ and _animal_, and perhaps define _sentient_, for the purpose of this question (unless the species is clearly called a "sentient plant" in the show).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Phylosians from 'The Infinite Vulcan' ST: TAS S01E07 (1973)

[image]

It might not fit exactly, but apparently in early drafts of 'This Side of Paradise' the Omicron spores from Omicron Ceti II were a communal intelligence.

Comment: [Infinite Vulcan on Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Infinite_Vulcan_(episode))

Comment: In the context of all the possible xenobiologies, what exactly makes these guys plants?   I mean, to me, the defining feature of a plant would be that it doesn't really have a fixed body plan, just a pattern, and something about maybe lacking a nervous system and musculature?    I don't think these are plants, if you ask me.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: that's a completely separate issue to the question asked.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Biology cares naught about your definition and opinion. Especially fantasy alien biology. Even on Earth life doesn't fit into convenient little boxes like that.  They're artifices to help humans organize.  And don't forget that we already have moving, carnivorous plants here.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy,  sure.  But in the context of what *plant* means on Earth,  we can appeal to common lineage.   In the context of exobiology, it really raises the question of what *being a plant*, even means.   I'm raising the issue,  not proposing a definition.

Comment: @ThePopMachine A good example would be Zhaan from Farscape - everyone calls her a plant, but she's clearly a humanoid life form descended from some plant-like species on her home planet that keeps some traits we commonly associate with plants (e.g. she's photosynthetic, if not fully autotrophic). If the same thing happened on Earth, would we call her species a plant? I'd expect her to create an entirely new group - related by lineage, but so different it doesn't make sense to call her a plant, just like we don't usually call birds dinosaurs, or reptiles, or fish, or...

Comment: @ThePopMachine In the end, all the categories in biology are heuristic (and partially hereditary). There's no strict boundaries. There's plants with nervous systems. There's plants with musculature. There's plants with very definite body plans, comparable to an animal. None of these are enough to make them "not plants", but at some point, we say "Okay, this is it - that's too many pattern breaks to keep them in the same category". But in fictional exobiology, there's a long tradition to alluding to origins - e.g. an aquatic species doesn't necessarily mean a being that actually lives in water.

Comment: @Luaan Wasn't her description slightly more nuanced in the way you suggest, the very first time it was explained to Crichton?  Then simplified to "plant" every other mention?

Comment: @The PopMachine Why not ask this as it's own question.

Comment: @wcullen:   I don't think there'd be any useful answer because I don't think this was very well thought out in that one TAS episode.

Answer (score 14):

Since the animated series counts, there are [the Phylosians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Infinite_Vulcan_(episode)):

[image]

They kidnap Spock and make a 25-foot tall clone of him.

Comment: [Infinite Vulcan on Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Infinite_Vulcan_(episode))

Comment: In the context of all the possible xenobiologies, what exactly makes these guys plants?   I mean, to me, the defining feature of a plant would be that it doesn't really have a fixed body plan, just a pattern, and something about maybe lacking a nervous system and musculature?    I don't think these are plants, if you ask me.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I don't know about real world definitions, but the episode repeatedly refers to them as plants, so as far as Star Trek universe is concerned they're plants.

Answer (score 14):

In the TNG episode [Shades of Grey](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shades_of_Gray_(episode)), Riker is attacked by a vine that demonstrates a basic level of sentience. It attacks living things, but not Data, and writhes when they cut off its thorn.

[image]

Comment: Nothing is this answer at all indicates sentience to me. I see a vine that can detect organic molecules and tries to escape when injured. Purely mechanical.

Comment: I immediately thought of this one as well, do don't worry lol.  Agree that this is just a defense mechanism, like a cuddly cholla cactus.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I'd attribute this answer to sci-fi's longstanding sentient/sapient terminology issue.

Answer (score 12):

Since there seems to be no animal life on the planet [Pahvo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pahvo) from *Discovery* season 1 episode 8, the sentient [Pahvans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pahvan) presumably originated as plant life of some kind.

Comment: Yeah, the planet that can be a space sonar (facepalm) was able to decide to contact the Klingons

Answer (score 4):

in DS9 Julian mentions that Ensign Vilix'pran is "budding" with twins.

[Vilix'pran](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vilix%27pran)

Comment: Is there any evidence that he was a plant other than using the word "budding"?

Comment: There are animal species that reproduce via budding; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budding#Animal_reproduction. (If anything, I'd say that that term is *more* commonly applied to animals than to plants.)

Comment: @colmde Apparently the young need a hatchling pond (amphibian?) and have wings (not amphibian), so...they're kind of all over the place.  But neither of those things sound "plant-like" to me.  He just seems to have been meant to sound like everything.

Comment: @ruakh Interesting, the two primary examples in that link - corals and sponges - I always thought were plants.  And apparently they were both classified as such for centuries, for a short time had a third designation (neither plant nor animal), and then got classified as animals by a very strict definition that can't be seen with the naked eye.

Answer (score 3):

The plants in **This SIde of Paradise** seem to have some intelligence - they turn to shoot spores into people who aren't already space-hippie-zombies.

[image: Spock is already a space-hippie-zombie]

They also seem to have some sort of control over people who get sprayed - they want to protect the plants and expand the plants' control over other people. I'm not sure if this fits your definition of Sentience.

> [Farmyard]
>
> KIRK: Spock, is that you?
>
> [Pasture]
>
> SPOCK: Yes, Captain. What did you want?
>
> KIRK [OC]: Where are you?
>
> SPOCK: I don't believe I want to tell you.
>
> [Farmyard]
>
> KIRK: Spock, I don't know what you think you're doing, but this is an
>   order. Report back to me at the settlement in ten minutes. We're
>   evacuating all colonists to Starbase Twenty Seven.
>
> [Pasture]
>
> SPOCK: No, I don't think so.
>
> [Farmyard]
>
> KIRK: You don't think so, what?
>
> [Pasture]
>
> SPOCK: I don't think so, sir.

Comment: 'The Starfleet Survival Guide' (D. Mack) does state that there is a symbiotic relationship between the spores and the hosts based upon neurochemical bonds. However, it goes on to state that this explains the symptoms of serotonin release. No explanation about actual sentient interaction is proved in the entry. Also, I'm not sure the book counts as canon.

Comment: The Omicron spores are iffy. Notes in an early draft state that they have a "communal intelligence," but this changed by the final draft/episode. The spores infect a person, but there's no evidence that the spores control them--it appears to be an attribute of the infection much like being protected from the otherwise dangerous berthold rays. Once infected, strong human emotions overcome the infection. The spores infect humans but are not in a symbiotic or parasitic-like relationship (and, in earlier drafts, it was blood-type or alcohol that thwarted the spores, not emotions).